# Does using ILM Policy for changing phases always require the index to be time series oriented?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elk

I have an index which has non time series data for my transaction details , it has fields like transaction_date but not exactly time series matched , so can i use ILM policy for it , and if not is there any other way to do what ILM does .

Also i wanted the data to be put into different ILM phases based on the transaction_date present in the documents , instead of the standard document_creation_date which gets used , is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

@khendricks Considering your indices are not TSD based, are they being rolled over in some pattern ? IF yes, then ofcourse you can use ILM policies for housekeeping purpose.

Comment: and what about using the transaction_date field instead of the standard document_creation_date , because rollover and change of phases generally happens based on document_creation_date. So how can i change that to transaction_date

Comment: What date field is being used inside the index is not something ILM care about. For ILM, the main thing is index creation date and after what age, those indices must be moved to next phases.